# Javascript clearInterval usage

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which I'm using to create a timer that counts up:

```
<h1><label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label></h1>
<button onclick="loadHard()">Reset All</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadHard() {
drawImage('image.png', 268, 5);
console.log('idle');
clearInterval(setTime);
}

var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime()
{
++totalSeconds;
secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
}
```

However, when I click my Reset All button, the timer keeps on counting and won't reset to 0. Is there a way to reset the timer back to 0, that I'm missing from this?

Comment: `setInterval` returns an id, you need to call `clearInterval(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
function loadHard() {
    drawImage('image.png', 268, 5);
    console.log('idle');
    // Clears the interval based on the id
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    // This will reset
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = secondsLabel.innerHTML = "00";
}

var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
// Notice we assign setInterval to an id
// The id can be used to clear the interval
var intervalId = setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime()
{
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
}
```

Alternatively, if you just wanted to reset the *timer* but keep the clock ticking, you could do:

```
function loadHard() {
    drawImage("image.png", 268, 5);
    totalSeconds = -1;
    setTime(); // Updates the time to 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's stopped the clock, however it seems stuck on x seconds after pressing Reset..

Comment: @user3293367 Do you want to keep the clock going but reset the clock to zero, or reset the clock and stop the clock?

Answer (score 3):

`clearInterval` doesn't take a function. It takes a "ticket", or "registration" or whatever you want to call it. Basically, you need to save the result from `setInterval` like this:

```
var ticket;
function test() {
    console.log('running test');
}

function schedule() {
    ticket = setInterval(test, 1000);
}

function unschedule() {
    clearInterval(ticket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<h1><label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label></h1>
<button onclick="loadHard()">Reset All</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout;
function loadHard() {
drawImage('image.png', 268, 5);
console.log('idle');
clearInterval(timeout);
}

var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;

timeout=setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime()
{
++totalSeconds;
secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, the timer has stopped, but I need it to be able to begin counting from 0 again after pressing Reset?

Answer (score 0):

Like Alxandr answered:
You can assign an ID to the interval like this:

```
var ticket;
function test() {
    console.log('running test');
}

function schedule() {
    ticket = setInterval(test, 1000);
}

function unschedule() {
    clearInterval(ticket);
}
```

But In your case this would also do:

```js
function test() {
   alert("hey");
}
 
function start(){
  setInterval(test, 0);
}
 
function unschedule() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 99; i++)
        window.clearInterval(i);
}
```